# Why int(11) on database integer columns?

Tags: database

Really this queation is not important it is just for the sake of curiosity.

Why some many columns in Joomla DB schema and other components use integer with size 11.

Why size 11, an odd number, instead of 10 for instance.

It is something related to performance?

Comment: Have a read of this: https://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the default *width to display* the column at when the table's data is being viewed via the MySQL console in MySQL for INT. http://waynewhitty.ie/blog-post.php?id=19

An INT column will always have a maximum value of 2147483647.